# Passing Array to JAVAScript from c# controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building on object list in c# and returning it as `return Json(thisVar)`
from my controller as  `public async Task<JsonResult>`
Then in my CSHTML I have this:

```
$.get(url,
      dataObject, 
      function (response) {
         alert(response);
         var allRes = JSON.parse(response);
```

my first alert show `[object Object]`

but get an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: You might want to try `console.log(response)` instead. It'll give a batter idea of what the response actually contains.

Comment: so I did that, thanks for the tip. my object is there, so its an array of riskPoint..how do I loop through that?
Object
riskPoint: Array(1965)
[0 … 99]
0: {lat: 51.332578469, lng: -2.426501671, gnd: 0, air: 0.000042978}

Comment: is it just response.riskPoint and then do a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `response` is already an object - there is no need to parse it.

```
...
function (response) {
    var arr = response.riskPoint;
    for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        // read arr[i];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your 1st alert showing a JS object then your object is already JSON parsed and you don't need to `JSON.parse`

The server probably returns the array wrapped in an object, like response.thisVar, if you do console.log you'll find it

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer was that It was already jsoon so I needed to loop through and just use the json object. I had to use labels in [] for the field names
Thanks for all the answers. console.log was especially helpful

Answer (score -1):

`JSON.parse()` is to convert text into a JavaScript object, not vice-versa.

Can you recheck your code? The response is already a JSON. JSON.stringify will help you to print it to text.

eg:

```
`var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');`
```

Comment: well now I am looping through the objects and each one (when I log to console looks something like this: {lat: 51.336565518, lng: -2.432768376, gnd: 0, air: 0.000038359}. this looks like a json object doesn't it? how do I ask for lat for one of these?